# Just wanted to thank you all

Tags: support

I love you all so much, seriously...

Gilles, Tripleee, Jeff Schaller, dirkt, slm, Stéphane Chazelas. Kusalananda, slm, terdon, mikeserv, and many others I can't remember names of right now, I am highly inspired by you all.

I am sorry to have typed this message like a coward like this. But I fear that you might feel like I am trying to be some catchy eye person mentioning your names in my post to highlight my name in your eyes. I don't know how you might take my statement which is why I made this new account just to thank you all for making such a great community. I would always be thankful to all of you who made this community so much helpful for freshers and experienced too. No matter how long a question is, I have seen answers on almost all of them in detail. I do understand that StackExchange has built an awesome platform but it would not have been this awesome you were not there. Thank you from my bottom of the heart to be so helpful to all, beginners and experienced.

I really love you all.

Although we are all strangers to one another, but I wish I could hug you all one day.

-No One

Comment: We all appreciate your kind words, this is perfectly fine to say this here in the meta.